# Must I format my USB disk even if it is already FAT32?

Tags: installation, usb

I am learning django (a high-level Python Web framework). and I am interested in ubuntu.

My OS is WIN8 and I decide to create a bootable USB stick with the tool *Pen Drive Linux's USB*.

I already have a FAT32 USB disk. There are already some files in it and 10 GB space left.

here are the questions:

1.Is ubuntu 12.04 better than Win8 in web development?

2.Could I install ubuntu alongside the existing files in my USB disk?

3.Is formatting USB disk before installing better than not formatting it?

Thank you!

Comment: @Avinash Raj oh sorry, I will notice that next time

Comment: Depends on what platform you are developing for, like what system is on the server, windows/linux.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can't tell you.
2. I don't use Pendrive, but you'll be able to install Ubuntu on a FAT-32 USB drive without having to format it with UNetBootin.
3. You can do wathever you want, as far as I know. Either seems fine, and either worked for me in the past.

Comment: thank you. but how to choose your answer as accepted one? there seems no bottun.

Comment: There should be a little "V" at the left of my answer, below the up-and-down arrows. Click on it :)